# Typescript: compilerOptions.outDir and non-ts modules

Tags: typescript, module

I have a problem with non-ts modules (text assets) that they don't get carried over to the outDir as configured in tsconfig.json (or I'm not doing it right).

Here's the simplest repro case

```
// /src/main.ts
import text from 'text.dat'
console.log( text )

// /src/a.d.ts
declare module 'text.dat' {
    const value: string;
    export default value
}

// /tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                      
    "module": "system",                   
...
    "outFile": "./public/bundle.js",      
    "outDir": "./public",                  
...

// /public/a.html
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        SystemJS.import('main');
    </script>
...
```

This results in a HTTP 404 when the transpiled javascript tries to load my text module as http://localhost:8082/text.dat but the original file is in the /src folder and does not get copied over to /public.

What am I missing?

FWIW the full repro case source is at https://github.com/duzenko/typescript-non-ts-module-bundle

Answer (score 1):

This unfortunately isn't supported inside the typescript compiler [Typescript Github Issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10939)

What I'd recommend you do, if you're using yarn or NPM, is have a script that moves those files to the right place *after* a successful compilation. Say you have a file in src `src/foo/bar.biz`. after you run `tsc` and output to the `./build` directory then run a manual `cp src/foo/bar.biz build/foo/bar.biz`